# Azure Notification Hub no longer accepting GCM API Key

Tags: android, cordova, azure, google-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

Recently, every time I try to add or modify the GCM API Key in an Azure Notification Hub, I get the following error:

> SubCode=40000. Failed to validate credentials with GCM. The remote
>   server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized...

I have tried using the same key that works in other Notification Hubs, as well as creating a new one via the Google Developer's console.

I've also recently come across articles stating that GCM is moving to FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). Could this be the cause of my issue? Is Google beginning to no longer support GCM?

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. The problem that I am facing is I can't seem to create the "Server Key". At least, I don't see that option under "Create credentials" in Google Cloud Console.

Comment: Hi Matt, I have resolved my issue. I set the "Key restriction" for that API key to "IP addresses" and have the value set to "0.0.0.0/0", which allows all ipv4 addresses. In doing so, I was able to bypass the Unauthorized error. Hope this works for you also. :)

Comment: Thanks Ming, Worked, you saved me alot of searching

Comment: @Ming your's is the correct answer. This is accurate because in production you would have to have some security anyway. Please post your answer and have the asker accept it as correct answer

Comment: I think @Ming s answer is correct.. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 30):

There are two important informations:

- [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) is the new version of GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/)

So we should prefer [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)  instead of [Google Cloud Console,](https://console.developers.google.com)

- There is a useful article here [Enabling Google Cloud Messaging (Firebase)](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204972667-Android-Enabling-Google-Cloud-Messaging-Firebase-in-Your-Android-Apps)

So we need to enable Google Cloud Messaging in Firebase Console for your added Android App.

Step by step:

-- Open your Firebase Console

-- Add your Android app in Firebase Console.

-- Go to **Settings**

-- Click **CLOUD MESSAGING** tab.

-- Take **Legacy Server key** there and use it in Azure Push Notification Service for **Google(GCM)** settings and Save it. That's all.

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started) article helps you how to create a Notification Hub Service in Azure then how to connect your Android or IOS App to Firebase Console etc.

Comment: Migrate your project to Firebase if you already have a legacy "google cloud messaging". Then use "Cloud Messaging tab" to get key. That will make it work for legacy apps.

Comment: "API Key" was the wrong key. Didn't know there was a "Legacy Server Key." That was the trick.

Comment: Azure Notification Hub still doesn't seem to be supporting FCM today. With today's FCM console I had to enable the old API (from Google Libraries) and get the key from there

Answer (score 1):

Could you make sure that 1) you have enabled **Google Cloud Messaging for Android** in your cloud push account and 2) you are creating a new **Server Key**?

Also, use try [sending a push notification from the command line](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/step-07?hl=en) to validate that the key is working with GCM directly. If that works, then Azure portal should accept the key. If that's not the case, please leave a comment.